# visual studio comment generate tool

Tags: c++, visual-studio, comments

I wonder what tool could generate comment like this in visual studio? Especially the capability of create the diagram like the comment shown at below.

```
//
//  +---------------+
//  |               |
//  | start_connect |<---+
//  |               |    |
//  +---------------+    |
//           |           |
//  async_-  |    +----------------+
// connect() |    |                |
//           +--->| handle_connect |
//                |                |
//                +----------------+
//                          :
// Once a connection is     :
// made, the connect        :
// actor forks in two -     :
//                          :
// an actor for reading     :       and an actor for
// inbound messages:        :       sending heartbeats:
//                          :
//  +------------+          :          +-------------+
//  |            |<- - - - -+- - - - ->|             |
//  | start_read |                     | start_write |<---+
//  |            |<---+                |             |    |
//  +------------+    |                +-------------+    | async_wait()
//          |         |                        |          |
//  async_- |    +-------------+       async_- |    +--------------+
//   read_- |    |             |       write() |    |              |
//  until() +--->| handle_read |               +--->| handle_write |
//               |             |                    |              |
//               +-------------+                    +--------------+
//
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt you'll find anything that integrates in Visual Studio, but you may be interested in [AsciiFlow](http://www.asciiflow.com/), an online ASCII flow-chart generator (that you can copy-paste in your comments).

With that said, what you have up there is essentially architectural documentation. This kind of broad-stroke documentation should (almost) never be a part of comments. Comments should be brief, concise and to the point (especially if working in a team). For more information read one of the many resources out there (one of the popular ones around here is the [Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Comments)).

Flow-charts and the like are much better suited as a part of some sort of auxiliary documentation (like a design document or an API documentation) that is wholly human-readable - not buried deep in source files.

Comment: I would not recommend Google C++ Style Guide to my worst ennemy. Not that there is nothing worse it in there, but part of the recommendations are very specific to Google (avoid exceptions, thus avoid work in constructors, ...) and it's very hard for a newbie to understand what to keep and what to throw out...

Comment: I was recommending the Style Guide mostly for the comment section (hence the #comments anchor) -- which I think is a good resource whatever programming language you may be using. I agree that other parts may be too specific.